# Forward decleration changes function behaviour?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, syntax, forward-declaration

I'm learning C++ and just found something strange that I would like to understand (see comment on the 5th line of the code):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// WITH this forward decleration the output is A=1 and B=2
// WITHOUT this forward decleration the output is A=2 and B=1
// WHY??
void swap(int a, int b);

int main() {

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    swap(a, b);

    cout << "A: " << a << endl;
    cout << "B: " << b << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

void swap(int a, int b) {
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour please? I thought that by default c++ passes by value unless you use the amperstand (&) in front of the function parameter like this:

```cpp
function swap(int &a, int &b) {
```

Comment: And if you remove both that and the using directive, it fails to compile, like you'd expect.

Comment: @chris Not really, there's `std::swap` which implements the correct swap (unlike his).

Comment: @0x499602D2, Yes, I know. [Here's what I mean](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5f34aaf54dfd956).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your swap function does not swap the original arguments. It swaps copies of the original arguments that will be destroyed after exiting the function. If you want that the function would indeed swap original arguments then the parameters have to be declared as referemces

```
void swap(int &a, int &b) {
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

When there is no forward declaration of your function in the program then it seems the compiler selects standard function `std::swap` that swaps original arguments. The standard function `std::swap` is considered by the compiler due to the using directive

```
using namepsace std;
```

If you remove it and remove the forward declaration of your function then the compiler will issue an error.

When the forward declaration of your function is present then the compiler selects your function because it is the best match as non-template function.

Comment: Pretty much the same answer as R Sahu but with some more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation of `swap` swaps the values locally in the function since its arguments are passed by value. It does not change anything in the calling function.

When you don't have that function declaration, `std::swap` is used, which does the right thing.